# Raster calculator using django

Tags: web-gis, django, django-raster

I want to create a web application that takes in 5 images does some calculation and shows the result on a basemap. all these images would be on geotif format single band and with values on pixels, I want to show the output of all images on a basemap and download option  also.
Users will connect to my website and upload these files hit submit and would be redirected to next page where output would be displayed.

I have installed django on my server and developed front-end how to connect it to backend, for example a gdal operation in backend that will give output.